# How come does the output add [1, 1, 1] instead of [1] here?

Tags: python, list, insert, range

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
for v in range(len(my_list)):
  my_list.insert(1, my_list[v])
print(my_list)
print(my_list[v])
print(v)
print(len(my_list))
```

The output is then:

```py
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
1
2
6
```

I am completely lost as to how three 1s are added to my_list. Can someone explain?

Comment: Follow your code in action at http://pythontutor.com…

Comment: welcome and please check [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

`Insert(pos, val)` inserts val as a new item to your list at position pos. Since len(my_list)=3 initially, the loop is executed 3 times:

1. `my_list[0]=1` is inserted to position 1, making `my_list = [1, 1, 2, 3]`
2. `my_list[1] = 1` is inserted to position 1 giving `my_list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]`
3. Same as in step 1 and 2: `my_list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the my_list in every iteration.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
for v in range(len(my_list)):
  my_list.insert(1, my_list[v])
```

let us under that, initially the list has 3 values which is why the **for** loop runs 3 times.

**1st Iteration:**

```
my_list[v] ==> my_list[0] ==> 1
hence ==> my_list.insert(1, 1)
my_list = [1, 1, 2, 3]
```

**2nd Iteration:**

```
my_list[v] ==> my_list[1] ==> 1
hence ==> my_list.insert(1, 1)
my_list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

**3rd Iteration:**

```
my_list[v] ==> my_list[2] ==> 1
hence ==> my_list.insert(1, 1)
my_list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Please let me know if you still have any questions around it. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You are inserting three times the value 1 at the position 0, 1 and 2. Therefore, the array is:

```
v = 0 -> [1, *1*, 2, 3]
v = 1 -> [1, *1*, 1, 2, 3]
v = 2 -> [1, *1*, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Moreover, I don't understand how you can print v if that variable can only be used within the `for`.

Comment: I downvoted because this is incorrect. The the value `1` _is_ inserted, but always at position `1`.

Comment: I fixed, sorry.